# How to change ‘selected’ option after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

This fiddle shows that the dropdown starts at ‘One’. What I want to happen is that the dropdown to start at my default (One) and then once I select a different option (Two), when I refresh the page, the dropdown starts at ‘Two’ instead of ‘One’.

https://jsfiddle.net/USERALPHA32/7r59xkrf/

It should just be as simple as taking the newly selected value and making that the new default select option. I’ve tried a few ways but I cannot get it working. (below code not apart of the fiddle but just showing the concepts I tried in my actual code)

```
var nSel = $(‘option:selected’, this).detach();
$(this).prepend(nSel);
console.log(nSel.val());
//The above ’nSel’ is the correct value I’m clicking on.

//None of these below worked.

// $('#dropdown option:selected').val(nSel.val());
// console.log($('#dropdown option:selected').val(nSel.val()));
// $("#dropdown").val(nSel.val());
// $("#dropdown").val();
// console.log($("#dropdown").val(nSel.val()));
// $("#dropdown").find(':selected').val();
// $('select').find('option', nSel.val());
// $('#dropdown option:selected', nSel.val());
// $('#dropdown option:selected').val(nSel);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want that your data will be saved even after refresh,
you have to use **localStorage**.

Save your choose in localStorage and fetch him on page load.

When user choose an option you save it with this code:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "yourOption");
```

And on document load you check if key exists:

```
var data = localStorage.getItem("key");
if(data){
    // here you change dropdown value.
}
```

You can choose if you want to delete value in localStorage so in next page refresh it will be clean.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a value after refreshing the web you must use **cookies or localStorage** and then set this variable with the new value.

Instead the traditional refresh you want to "reflesh" with ajax, you can use a **global variable** in your js file.

**COOKIE**

**Set a cookie**

```
$.cookie("example", "foo"); // Sample 1 

$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 }); // Sample 2 

$.cookie("example", "foo", { path: '/admin', expires: 7 }); // Sample 3
```

**Get a cookie**

```
console.log( $.cookie("example") );
```

**Delete the cookie**

```
$.removeCookie("example");
```

**LOCALSTORAGE**

```
var data = localStorage.getItem("key");
if(data){
    // Code
}
```